# Lost records from DB with SQL HAVING

Tags: sql, count, having

I don't know why my query doesn't work fine.
When I'm trying to show any user with devices_count=0 it's not show.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT `u`.`id` AS `usersId`, `u`.`id_user` AS `usersIdUser`, `u`.`name` AS `usersName`,
       `u`.`postal` AS `usersPostal`, `u`.`city` AS `usersCity`,
       `u`.`street` AS `usersStreet`, `g`.`name` AS `geographyName`,
       `e`.`name` AS `expertsName`, `e`.`surname` AS `expertsSurname`,
       `o`.`name` AS `ownersName`, 
       COUNT(`d`.`id`) AS `devices_count` 
FROM `users` `u`
    LEFT JOIN `devices` `d` ON `u`.`id` = `d`.`user_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `owners` `o` ON `d`.`comm_id`=`o`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `experts` `e` ON `d`.`expert_id`=`e`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `geography` `g` ON `u`.`voivod`=`g`.`id`
WHERE `d`.`expert_id` LIKE '%' AND `u`.`id` LIKE 3332
  AND `u`.`voivod` LIKE '%' AND `u`.`city` LIKE "%" AND `u`.`status` LIKE '%'
GROUP BY `u`.`id`
HAVING COUNT(d.id) BETWEEN 0 AND 99999
ORDER BY devices_count ASC LIMIT 0, 20
```

User with id 3332 it's in DB, but with 0 installed devices (devices_count=0). Of course without narrowing results by WHERE clausule it's still doesn't showing all results. All fields and JOINed columns are necessary.

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause is turning the `left join`s into inner joins.

You need to move the filtering logic to the `on` clauses for all but the first table:

```
FROM `users` `u`
    LEFT JOIN `devices` `d` ON `u`.`id` = `d`.`user_id` and `d`.`expert_id` LIKE '%'
    LEFT JOIN `owners` `o` ON `d`.`comm_id`=`o`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `experts` `e` ON `d`.`expert_id`=`e`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `geography` `g` ON `u`.`voivod`=`g`.`id`
WHERE  `u`.`id` LIKE 3332 AND
       `u`.`voivod` LIKE '%' AND `u`.`city` LIKE "%" AND `u`.`status` LIKE '%'
```

Comment: You're right @Gordon, now it work's perfect - thanks a lot!